# Mysql gem fail when running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to `bundle install` the Rails project I pulled from GitHub. However, I run in [this issue.](http://pastebin.com/cAjhK1qE) Here is my [Gemfile.](http://pastebin.com/XmK8b7bn)

I can't get this to work. Any opinions what might go wrong here?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the mysql dev packages to compile the native extension.

Answer (score 2):

On ubuntu you need to install libmysqlclient-dev package using the command

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Thanks. Fortunately the package name was same for openSUSE distro, and this is exactly what was missing.